# locating an element in a string and comparing it in C

Tags: c, arrays, string, strcmp

I'm having trouble with what I think is a segfault when I attempt to access a specific element of a string.  Specifically, I'm trying to determine the letter at the end of 'longitude' and check whether it's a 'W' or not.  However, I end up crashing before I even get to the strcmp part.
Here's the code:

```
int main{
    int Val;
    char longitude[20] = "081-28-23.2590W";
    char direction = longitude[14];         //pretty sure it's crashing on this line

    printf("%s\n", direction);              //this does not print

    Val = strcmp(direction, "W");           //And I think this is right, but not sure
    if(Val==0)
    { DO STUFF;}
    else{DO MORE STUFF}
}
```

Also, I'm not even sure if the strcmp part is correct, as the program crashes before it gets there.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

`printf("%s\n", direction);` Is the problem.

`direction` is a single character while `%s` tells `printf` to expect a 0 terminated string.

Also, standard naming convention would be `val` not `Val`, and perhaps something more like `isEast` (since `strcmp` returns 0/false for 'W').
I assume you have got the correct `main() { ... }` - your question has it wrong. You should just cut and paste the real code so people don't address the red herrings.

As @Kaylum points out, I missed the same problem in `strcmp` which compares 2 strings not one character and one string. In this case you can just say `isWest = (direction == 'W');` instead of using `strcmp`.

For the sake of completeness you could leave it all "as is" by saying `char *direction = &longitude[14];` now `direction` is a 0 terminated string and so printf and strcmp work. I would suggest this is not a good solution...

Comment: Thank you for the clarifications, and yes, main() is correct in the actual code.  And your suggestions, along with @Kaylums worked perfectly and are extremely helpful.  I attempted to make a simpler version of the code, as the actual code is very lengthy.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to determine the letter at the end of 'longitude'

```
char longitude[20] = "081-28-23.2590W";
//...
size_t n = strlen( longitude ); 
char direction = n == 0 ? '\0' : longitude[n-1];

// ...
printf("%c\n", direction);              
       ^^^
```

> and check whether it's a 'W' or not

```
if ( toupper( ( unsigned char )direction ) == 'W' )
{
    //...
}
else
{
    //...
}
```